# How to solve overheating in Dell laptops while using Ubuntu 12.04 and later versions?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, overheating

I have Dell N5010 laptop with Intel's i5 processor (1st generation), 4 GB of RAM.
I have been using Ubuntu for a quite long time ,since the versions 10.04 and later versions.
My Laptop was getting super-heated and shutting down automatically after the temperature rose to some threshold level.
On the other hand, it didn't heat that much in windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had cleaned up my sink-fans,kept laptop at some elevation from table/bed surface. Improved Airflow. But, nothing worked for me.
This Jupiter tool worked for me.
I am using it in power-saving mode and no performance degradation issues.
I can carry out my normal functionality.
Here is the link :-

**http://itsfoss.com/solve-overheating-issue-in-ubuntu-12-10/**

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on Dell inspiron 3521 - Ubuntu 13.04 . Less sound of fan webupd8.org/2011/06/linux-kernel-power-issue-fix.html (Using tlp as well - webupd8.org/2013/04/improve-power-usage-battery-life-in.html)